# Why does the derivate of (x+1)^2 not equal 2?

Tags: derivatives

$$f(x) = (x+1)^2$$

$$f'(x) = 2(x+1)$$

Shouldnt it equal 2 because, the rules of derivation says that

- the derivation of any number equals 0
- the derivation of x^2=2x*1=2

$$(x+1)^2 =x^2+1$$

$$1=0$$

$$x^2=2x=2$$

$$2+0=2$$

Comment: the derivation of 1 = 0 and of 2x = 2

Comment: @L. F. why you deleted your comment? I answered you!

Comment: looks like this site doesn't have empathy with newbies - just made a proof of that :)

Comment: From what I know the chain rule tells me that $f'(x)=2(x+1)'(x+1)^{2-1}$

Comment: @Module I used another method to calculate the derivative, your rule can be used. what I did was removing exponet and then calculating the derivation using the method above.

Comment: You had an error when foiling it. Always remember what you've learned in algebra: $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$

Comment: BTW,. I study Maths in another language, so if something was translated wrong, here's what I mean: 1)Exponet: what appers above the function (e.g $$x^2$$) 2)calculating the derivation using the method above: I mean after getting rid of the exponet, I used the normal derivatives rules (e.g $$A$$ = 0, $$Ax = A$$ ..etc) just to not be understood incorrectly :)

Comment: @Module I always forget the basics, this is always causing me troubles :-(

Comment: I understood exactly what you said, but if you want to further develop you need to get the basics down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mistake is not calculus related:
$$(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1$$

You have (incorrectly) written that:
$$(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 1^2$$

Thus, you can easily see the derivative should be $2x+2$.

Comment: stupid me! I forgot something like that - thanks